# iPhone 5 CSS media query

Tags: iphone, css, responsive-design, media-queries, iphone-5

The iPhone 5 has a longer screen and it's not catching my website's mobile view. What are the new responsive design queries for the iPhone 5 and can I combine with existing iPhone queries?

My current media query is this:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {}
```

Comment: Can we see your existing media queries?

Comment: Try this? http://halgatewood.com/iphone-5-media-query/

Answer (score 287, accepted):

Another useful media feature is `device-aspect-ratio`.

Note that the **iPhone 5 does not have a 16:9 aspect ratio**. It is in fact 40:71.

iPhone < 5:
`@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 2/3) {}`

iPhone 5:
`@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {}`

iPhone 6:
`@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 375/667) {}`

iPhone 6 Plus:
`@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {}`

iPad:
`@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 3/4) {}`

Reference:
[Media Queries @ W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/CR-css3-mediaqueries-20020708/)

[iPhone Model Comparison](https://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/)

[Aspect Ratio Calculator](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/)

Comment: I like this approach but could not get it to work in a PhoneGap app webview until adding -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio as explained by Stephen Sprawl http://zsprawl.com/iOS/2012/09/css-media-queries-for-the-iphone-5.

@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    //iphone5 for teh phonegaps
}

Comment: I had to add `and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)` in iPhone 5 media query to make it work in PhoneGap webview as stated by @TaeKwonJoe

Comment: This works pretty well when I need differentiate iphone 4 and iphone 5 in css.

Comment: For iphone 6, (device-aspect-ratio: 667/375) did not work on a real physical iphone 6. It worked on the iOS simulator though. I changed it to 375/667 and it worked on the physical device.

Comment: Thanks 2C-B, you might want to switch 16/9 to 9/16 on 6+ to get it to work on device as well.

Comment: Does the aspect ratio use the portrait version of the phone? or can this also be used instead of orientation:landscape/portrait?

Comment: Yet another aspect ratio calculator: https://www.mzeeshan.me/aspectratio

Answer (score 65):

There is this, which I credit to [this blog](http://halgatewood.com/iphone-5-media-query/):

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 560px) and (max-device-width: 1136px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    /* iPhone 5 only */
}
```

Keep in mind it reacts the iPhone 5, not to the particular iOS version installed on said device.

To merge with your existing version, you should be able to comma-delimit them:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px), only screen and (min-device-width: 560px) and (max-device-width: 1136px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    /* iPhone only */
}
```

*NB: I haven't tested the above code, but I've tested comma-delimited `@media` queries before, and they work just fine.*

**Note that the above may hit some other devices which share similar ratios, such as the Galaxy Nexus.** Here is an additional method which will target only devices which have one dimension of 640px (560px due to some weird display-pixel anomalies) and one of between 960px (iPhone <5) and 1136px (iPhone 5).

```
@media
    only screen and (max-device-width: 1136px) and (min-device-width: 960px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (min-device-height: 560px),
    only screen and (max-device-height: 1136px) and (min-device-height: 960px) and (max-device-width: 640px) and (min-device-width: 560px) {
    /* iPhone only */
}
```

Comment: Can you suggest how I might combine this query with my old one to catch both iphone 4 and 5?

Comment: Careful as this will effect other phones as well - not just the iphones. An example being the Samsung Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: @MikeSweeney Good call. I've updated my post with a new method that should not include other devices.

Comment: @Eric That's pretty much what I wound up settling on after a bunch of cross-phone testing - had to bring height into the mix! Seems to be working great across the 7-8 various phones I test on.

Comment: is this line correct: `iPhone 5 and not to iOS 6`? Should it be: "iPhone5 and not to iPhone 6"?

Comment: @Sgnl Actually, the line is correct. But given the changes since the post was written, I'll edit it to be more clear.

Answer (score 39):

All these answers listed above, that use `max-device-width` or `max-device-height` for media queries, suffer from very strong bug: they also target **a lot of other popular mobile devices** (probably unwanted and never tested, or that will hit the market in future).

This queries will work for **any device that has a smaller screen**, and probably your design will be broken.

Combined with similar device-specific media queries (for HTC, Samsung, IPod, Nexus...) this practice will launch a time-bomb. For debigging, this idea can make your CSS an uncontrolled spagetti. You can never test all possible devices.

Please be aware that the only media query **always targeting IPhone5 and nothing else**, is:

```
/* iPhone 5 Retina regardless of IOS version */
@media (device-height : 568px) 
   and (device-width : 320px) 
   and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
/* and (orientation : todo: you can add orientation or delete this comment)*/ {
                 /*IPhone 5 only CSS here*/
}
```

Note that **exact** width and height, not max-width is checked here.

---

Now, what is the solution? If you want to write a webpage that will look good on all possible devices, the best practice is to you use degradation

/* degradation pattern
     we are checking screen width only
     sure, this will change is turning from portrait to landscape*/

```
/*css for desktops here*/

@media (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  /*IPad portrait AND netbooks, AND anything with smaller screen*/
  /*make the design flexible if possible */
  /*Structure your code thinking about all devices that go below*/
}
@media (max-device-width: 640px) {
 /*Iphone portrait and smaller*/
}
@media (max-device-width: 540px) {
 /*Smaller and smaller...*/
}
@media (max-device-width: 320px) {
 /*IPhone portrait and smaller. You can probably stop on 320px*/
}
```

If more than 30% of your website visitors come from mobile, turn this scheme upside-down, providing mobile-first approach. Use `min-device-width` in that case. This will speed up webpage rendering for mobile browsers.

Comment: I would go progressive enhancement and mobile first. That is beginning with mobile and building up using min-device-width.

Comment: Also note that the height/width/pixel-ratio solution that only matches the iPhone 5 will also match the next phone that appears that happens to have the same characteristics. The overall theme of your answer is correct: thinking in terms of *specific devices* is the wrong way to proceed.

Comment: @Dan – even though your answer doesn't directly address the question, it looks at it within a wider perspective of best practices for responsive design. Things you wrote here, in my opinion, are very deep and practical. Five stars.

Comment: @Dan – trying to implement your suggestion, something is not working. May I please ask you to take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486078/only-the-smallest-max-device-width-media-query-is-applied

Comment: @primavera, please say why. What is the advantage of a mobile first approach?

Comment: Setting base css for those devices with least processor power. CSS overrides pointed to those (desktop etc) with more power.

Answer (score 8):

for me, the query that did the job was:

```
only screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```

Answer (score 8):

iPhone 5 in portrait & landscape

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) {

/* styles*/
}
```

iPhone 5 in landscape

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { 
/* styles*/

}
```

iPhone 5 in portrait

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { 
 /* styles*/

}
```

Comment: Why do you need `max-device-width : 568px` on portrait?

Comment: @adi518 if you don't use max-width then css rules are applied for any device greater than 320px which is like literally most of the devices - tablets desktops etc

Comment: Why not use `device-width: 320px and device-height: 568px` instead?

Answer (score 5):

None of the response works for me targeting a phonegapp App.

As the following [link](http://zsprawl.com/iOS/2012/09/css-media-queries-for-the-iphone-5/) points, the solution below works.

```
@media screen and (device-height: 568px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    // css here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just a very quick addition as I have been testing a few options and missed this along the way. Make sure your page has:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get your answer fairly easily for the iPhone5 along with other smartphones on the media feature database for mobile devices:

http://pieroxy.net/blog/2012/10/18/media_features_of_the_most_common_devices.html

You can even get your own device values on the test page on the same website.

(Disclaimer: This is my website)

Answer (score 0):

afaik no iPhone uses a pixel-ratio of 1.5

iPhone 3G / 3GS: (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)
iPhone 4G / 4GS / 5G: (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)

Answer (score 0):

```
/* iPad */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 768px) {
    /* ipad-portrait */
    @media screen and (max-width: 896px) { 
        .logo{
            display: none !important;
        }
    }
    /* ipad-landscape */
    @media screen and (min-width: 897px) { 

    }
}
/* iPhone */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    /* iphone-portrait */
    @media screen and (max-width: 400px) { 

    }
    /* iphone-landscape */
    @media screen and (min-width: 401px) { 

    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You should maybe down the "-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio" to 1.5 to catch all iPhones ?

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px), only screen and (min-device-width: 640px) and (max-device-width: 1136px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
/* iPhone only */
}
```

Comment: Which iPhone is using a device pixel ratio of 1.5?

Comment: I highly recommend to do media queries depending on device width, and not device name (iPhone). So if the iPhone 5 has more width, just make that usable.