# Remove anchor when in mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor

I want to remove the href of an image when one mobile phones..

```
<header id='top_header'>
    <a href='index.php'><img id='crest' src='../images/868crest.png' alt='868 RCACS Crest'></a>
    <img id='title' src='../images/newtitle.png' alt='868 RCACS Title'>
</header>
```

I currently don't have any javascript's or jquery so how can i do this if i cant do this with just html and css

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `@media` queries with `handheld` keyword and `pointer-event` property like

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    a {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dSCnG/) (Resize the screen and hover over the link)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/dSCnG/1/) (Nothing fancy, just changed the color, so that you can test it better)

[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/dSCnG/2/) (Using `handheld` won't target computers)

> Note: I've removed `handheld` from that demo to make it work as of
>   now.

Comment: This will unfortunately not catch all the phones out on the market now including the iPhone 5 which has `(max-device-width: 1136px)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539697/iphone-5-css-media-query

Comment: @DGS this not the piece of code which will cover all devices, I just gave him an idea, he can make the most out of it, you need to write media queries to target specific things, so if it's iphone, we can just put the same `a { pointer-events: none; }` inside that media query

Comment: Just wanted to make sure he knew it was not a catch all

Comment: @DGS, wouldn't `max-width: 568px` work for all iPhone versions if the viewport metatag was set correctly (100% width on iPhone5 landscape)?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand was trying to point out that targeting "mobile phones" with css media queries is a hard job since you may display that css on desktop browsers if the width is too wide but miss some of the bigger mobile screens if the width is too small.

Answer (score 2):

Detect mobile on window onload event then remove href

```
var remHref = function(){
    if(!!window.orientation){
       document.getElementById('crest').href = "#";
    }
}
// or use e.preventDefault() on link onclick event

window.onload = remHref
```