# how to define height in responsive design

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am working on a project for which i have to make responsive version of the website. The site is a one page website made with jquery,fixed height and width and absolute positioning. The contents of the site must fit in within the viewport of the browser, view it [here](http://atomiclabs.in/),

Now the problem is, i have to take care of not only the width but also the height of the screen, and if i target both fixed device height and width, the code will be huge, any suggestions, what i have planned to use,

```
@media screen and (max-width:479px) {...}
@media screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:639px) {...}
@media screen and (min-width:640px) and (max-width:959px) {...}
@media screen and (min-width:960px) and (max-width:1279px) {...}
@media screen and (min-width:1280px) and (max-width:1599px) {..}
@media screen and (min-width:1600px)  and (max-width:1919px){...}
@media screen and (min-width:1920px) {...}
```

but this does not give be desired results because fixed height percentage in the current design.

Please, any suggestions.

Comment: Maybe, this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12848217/3288548

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is - You have a 100% width and responsive height.

For this you can set width to 100% and use media queries for maintaining height.

I've done something similar [here](http://ketchupdesigns.com/EverDiva/).

See if it helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to set both width and height in each screen size.

In your case, the website's height is always 100%. What you need to take care of is just the content width.

for example, in large screen the content is 80% width, in small one the content may be 100% width;

I strongly recommend you to take a look at some css frameworks with grid system like [skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/#grid) and [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html). they are both great in responsive design, you may use and learn from it!

btw, to deal with background image, you can use css attr

```
-moz-background-size: cover;       
-webkit-background-size: cover;     
-o-background-size: cover;  
background-size: cover;
```

this may solve some problem!