# Bootstrap `.hidden-xs` does not hide div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to create a site, that will hide an extended section for users on a small screen using Bootstrap's `.hidden-xs` To test it, I am using Chrome's mobile emulator, setting it to "iPhone 5" (pretty small). When I refresh  the page, however, it does not hide the div. Am I using the class wrong?

*HTML*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/todo.css">
        <title>TODO</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <header>

            </header>
            <div id="left">
                <div class="test"></div>
                <div class="test"></div>
                <div class="test"></div>
                <div class="test"></div>
                <div class="test"></div>
                <div class="test"></div>
                <div class="test"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="main" class="hidden-xs">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*CSS*

```
/* CSS Document */

body {
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    height: 10em;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

#left {
    float: left;
    height: 80%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#main {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
}

.test {
    height: 10em;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    width: 100%
}

.test:hover {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

here is a JSFiddle demonstrating my code: https://jsfiddle.net/James_Parsons/jwqdbn61/

**EDIT**

Apparently an iPhone 5 is not small enough. If I use both `.hidden-xs` and `.hidden-sm` will it be hidden on all small devices?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone 5 CSS media query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539697/iphone-5-css-media-query)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iPhone5 width is 1136px so adding `hidden-sm` too won't help. You will need to add a custom media query to hide the `.main` like this:

```
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .main {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .main {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

**BUT** there are a lot of people using PCs and Laptops with a screen width in that range so you might end up hiding the div for them too.

If you want to hide the div on Phones/Tablets having a large width, then you might have to go with the old school **user-agent** device detection approach which involves using JavaScript to check if the device is a Phone/Tablet or not.

Also, as Kyle mentioned above, you need to define your `main` class as well as your `hidden-xx` query class together like this:

```
<div class="main hidden-xs">
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two issues here:

1. One is that the jsFiddle does not include the viewport tag so the device emulation does not try to resize the viewport.  Without that, you cannot take advantage of Bootstrap's responsive class sizes.  Make sure to include the following as the first item in your head element:

   ```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   ```

   [Here's a plunker that includes a runnable instance](http://plnkr.co/edit/Krzh8RgMPvXb5V3UuePY)
2. The other issue is that you have `class` defined twice in you main div:

   ```
   <div class="main" class="hidden-xs">
   ```

   So if you inspect the element, you'll actually notice that the second class is ignored and you never pull in `hidden-xs`.  Instead add them both separated by a space like this:

   ```
   <div class="main hidden-xs">
   ```

Now it should work fine:

[image: demo]

Comment: @James_Parsons, that's not very descriptive/helpful.  You mean using the emulator?  On a real device? Using the link I provided? Making the changes yourself?  The two things I pointed out were definitely impeding this from working.  When they cleared up, it worked for me. If you're using Bootstrap you need the meta viewport tag, so pretending there are more pixels and writing custom CSS for classes that are already provided isn't a very stable solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this add this css :

```
@media (max-width:767px){.hidden-xs{display:none!important}}
```